# Imprimir todas imagens de outra tabela sem repetir o titulo

Tags: php, foreach, while

Tenho as duas tabelas abaixo

tabela IMAGENS

```
id_imagens  | diretorio_imagem | post_id
       1        imagem1.jpg          1
       2        imagem2.jpg          1
       3        imagem3.jpg          1
       4        imagem4.jpg          1
       5        imagem5.jpg          2
       6        imagem6.jpg          2
       7        imagem7.jpg          2
       8        imagem8.jpg          2
```

Tabela POSTS

```
id_post   |          slug             |   titulo     
 1              titulo_do_post           Titulo do Post 
 2              titulo_do_post_2         Titulo do Post 2
```

PHP:

```
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts, imagens
WHERE posts.id_post = imagens.post_id
AND slug=:slug");
$stmt->execute(array(":slug"=>$_GET['slug']));
     while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
{
?> 

<h3>Você esta aqui:<?php print utf8_encode($row['titulo']);?></h3>

<!-- Start Anuncio-->
<div> 
   <img src="http://entreconnection.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Wide-Skyscrapper3.png" style="margin-top:50px;">
</div>
 <!--End Anuncio-->

<h1><?php print utf8_encode($row['titulo']);?></h1>

<img src="<?php print ($row['diretorio_imagem']); ?>">

 <div> 
        <!-- Start Anuncio-->
        <div style="text-align:center">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/help/hc/images/adsense/mobile-leaderboard.png" style="margin:20px;">
        </div>
        <!-- END Anuncio -->

        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/<?php print ($row['slug']); ?>" data-width="600" data-numposts="5"></div>

 </div>


<?php
}
?>
```

Acessando a página "Titulo do post 2"  imprime:

```
Titulo do post 2
imagem5.jpg

Titulo do post 2
imagem6.jpg

Titulo do post 2
imagem7.jpg

Titulo do post 2
imagem8.jpg
```

Como ter o resultado:

```
Titulo do post 2
imagem5.jpg
imagem6.jpg
imagem7.jpg
imagem8.jpg
```

Já entendi que pode ter uma verificação if ou fazer um group by na instrução sql, mas não esta entrando na minha cabeça como fazer a verificação se o titulo já existe antes de imprimir... ou se for usar o group by como fazer o foreach das imagens dentro do while

Agradeço ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de resolver isso é:

- Primeiramente vamos organizar os dados pelo título do post seguido do id da imagem:

  `SELECT * FROM posts, imagens WHERE posts.id_post = imagens.post_id AND slug=:slug ORDER BY posts.titulo, imagens.id_imagens`
- Depois siga o exemplo abaixo, fazendo um if dentro do while para ver se o título mudou, e imprima caso afirmativo:

  ```
  $slug = $_GET['slug'];
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts, imagens WHERE posts.id_post = imagens.post_id AND slug=:slug ORDER BY posts.titulo, imagens.id_imagens");
  $stmt->execute(array(":slug"=>$_GET['slug']));

  $titulo = '';
  $conteudo = '';
  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {

      if($row['titulo'] != $titulo) {

          $conteudo .= ($conteudo != '') ?
          '<div>
              <!-- Start Anuncio-->
              <div style="text-align:center">
                  <img src="https://www.google.com/help/hc/images/adsense/mobile-leaderboard.png" style="margin:20px;">
              </div>
              <!-- END Anuncio -->
              <div class="fb-comments" data-href="'.BASE_URL.'/'.$row['slug'].'" data-width="600" data-numposts="5"></div>
          </div>' : '';

          echo $conteudo;

          $conteudo = '<h3>Você esta aqui: '.utf8_encode($row['titulo']).'</h3>
          <!-- Start Anuncio-->
          <div> 
            <img src="http://entreconnection.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Wide-Skyscrapper3.png" style="margin-top:50px;">
          </div>
          <!--End Anuncio-->
          <h1>'.utf8_encode($row['titulo'])'</h1>';

          $titulo = $row['titulo'];
      }

      $conteudo .= '<img src="'.$row['diretorio_imagem'].'"> ';
  }
  ```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: obrigada resolve para imprimir o titulo apenas uma vez, mas nas os demais conteudos (propagandas e tags html) dentro do while continuam sendo duplicadas conforme a quantidade de imagens, fica inviável criar vários ifs

Comment: A solução que queria está resolvida, não estou entendendo o que quer agora, propagandas? Explique melhor oque quer.

Comment: Marquei como resolvido, pois realmente resolve a questão muito obrigada. Como comentei existem outros conteudos html dentro do while e em alguma partes tem tags php no caso do titulo e imagens, com sua solução o titulo imprime uma unica vez mas o restante do conteudo html é replicado conforme a quantidade de imagens

Comment: Que restante? Poste o que está saindo e o que espera sair pra tentarmos encontrar uma solução.

Comment: Na pergunta inseri algumas informações dentro do while para você ter uma ideia

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se funciona